# How to move data frome one volume to another

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, elastic-stack, persistent-volumes

I have deleted an elastic ECK cluster and redeployed a new one on GKE. But the new one does not take the old pv data. Is there a way to restore it or is it lost for good?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two clusters?

Comment: did you takeup the snapshot of old cluster ?

Comment: Here is an update: We have been able to restore data but the master nodes are stuck at "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires at least 2 nodes" which is the same error that ruined the first cluster